# Как вписать текст в RichEdit

Tags: delphi

Есть RichEdit в нем редактируется текст. Как сделать так, что бы кода текст, что печатается подходил к правому краю поля ввода, то он не переходил бы на новую строку, а к примеру, останавливался и ожидал нажатия клавишт Enter?

Comment: Сделать не сложно, просто зачем? А я пойду пока над кодом покумекаю.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте в свойстве `ScroolBars` значение `ssBoth`. Должно помочь =)

Comment: если выставляю свойство, как Вы написали, то при загрузке текста из БД вообще текст не грузится, отчего то

Comment: Не понял, что вы пытались сказать =) Расскажите поподробнее.